# OneDrive keeps creating copies of new files

Tags: copy, onedrive

I drop a new file into a Onedrive folder which had been shared with me and it instantly starts to create copies of it. For example if I drop in a `test.xlsl` I instantly start to see:

```
test.xlsl
test-1.xlsl
test-2.xlsl
test-3.xlsl
test-4.xlsl
test-5.xlsl
...
...
test-124.xlsl
```

and it goes on and on. Has somebody encountered this anomaly as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've finally managed to get the answer: I was simply logged in with a different e-mail address into my Microsoft account, not the same which one got the folder shared with.